# What is the expression for an oversampled signal?

Tags: signal, dsp

**Problem:** A simplified schematic of an oversampling circuit is shown below. A data sequence, \$x[n]\$, is transmitted by REG1 which is in clock domain \$C_{tx}\$. \$x[n]\$ is oversampled by REG2 in the clock domain \$C_{rx}\$, resulting in the sample sequence \$y[m]\$. The clock \$C_{tx}\$ has frequency \$f_{tx}\$ and the clock \$C_{rx}\$ has frequency \$f_{rx}\$ and the oversampling rate is defined as \$ \beta \in \mathbb{R} \$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhtkzE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Definitions:**

1. \$n = 0,1,2,\ldots \$
2. \$m = 0,1,2,\ldots \$
3. \$ \beta = f_{rx}/f_{tx} \$

**Question:**

What is \$y[m]\$, expressed in terms of \$x, n, m\$ and/or \$ \beta \$? Assume \$ \beta \geq 1\$. Also, REG1 and REG2 may be treated as zero-delay models: \$T_{propagation} = T_{setup} = T_{hold} = 0\$. For simplicity, you may assume \$\phi_{tx}(0) = \phi_{rx}(0) = 0\$, where \$\phi_{tx}(t)\$ is the phase of \$C_{tx}\$ at time \$t\$, and \$\phi_{rx}(t)\$ is the phase of \$C_{rx}\$ at time \$t\$.

All answers are welcome, but the accepted answer must provide analytical proof of the proposed expression. Intuitive explanations or a few evaluated cases are not analytical proof.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?  It also seems like a trick question.

Comment: Its not a homework problem. This is a real problem I have run into while analyzing a clock-data recovery circuit I designed. It is no trick, I have evaluated an answer, but have not yet been able to prove it is correct. I wanted to get input from the community to see how people think about the problem, without contaminating people's ideas with my own.

Comment: @travis Ok.  I see you moved y[m] to the output of reg2.  When you posted it the first time y[m]=x[n].  By the way, what does this have to do with clock-data recovery?  You're just changing the time scale.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the figure was incorrect before so it was a trick question. So the problem above is a simplified example of asynchronous serial communication. The original data sequence, x[n], is sourced from REG1. It is received asynchronously by REG2, resulting in y[m]. y[m] is just an oversampled version of x[n]. The original data x[n] can be recovered in the digital domain from just y[m]. The recovery circuit is not shown because it is outside the scope of the question.

Comment: @travis Is there anything unclear with my answer? Accepting it would be fair I think as it really took some time.

Comment: Yes, definitely very helpful and it deserves accepting. I just thought I would leave the bounty open for as long as possible to see if there was any other helpful information. But I think yours is as good as I will ever get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I go with the answer of Vasiliy and proofed it.

$$y\left[m\right] = x\left[{\Big\lfloor{\frac{m}{\beta}}\Big\rfloor}\right]$$

As I really can't think while writing TeX and you may need this before the end of the month, I wrote on a tablet.

The solution is to describe the input signal *x* in the time domain. Then the output signal *y* is derived from *x* using natural sampling. Based on the knowledge about the clock domains (

- synchronized at time zero and
- receiver clock equal or faster then transmitter clock
- both clocks are exactly periodically

), the expression can be simplified.

[image]

**Edit:** The *clock relation* expression
$$n\left[m\right] = {\Big\lfloor{\frac{m}{\beta}}\Big\rfloor}$$
is not really obvious, but can be expressed very well using system theory. The idea is to describe the clock cycle count of the TX clock (TX clock value) as an integer value signal over time. This signal can be expressed using the floor function.

Then this signal is sampled using natural sampling at the positions of the RX clock events. In this way the counter value *n* of the slower TX clock can be expressed for all RX clock event positions *mT<sub>1</sub>*. Because the positions only depend on *m*, *n* can be expressed as a function of *m*.

[image]

Comment: "The solution is to describe the input signal x in the time domain. Then the output signal y is derived from x using natural sampling." Solid gold solution, I should have thought of that... I haven't fully assimilated written equations, but I need to spend more time.

Comment: OK, could you elaborate the step in red? How did you get \$n= \lfloor m/ \beta \rfloor\$ from the circuit? To me it looks a little like http://ojotaylor.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/then-a-miracle-occurs-cartoon.jpg

Comment: Also, I couldn't really understand how you get to the equation on the second to last line. Could you elaborate how you got \$y^*(t)\$?

Comment: Step in red: I agree, this is not really obvious, but I wasn't sure how to nail it down. Will update my post when I have some more time.

Comment: To the second last line (green/orange): y*(t) is a product of many (the sum) delta impulses with periode T1 (orange) multiplied with many rect pulses with another periode (green). -> different clock speeds. When a delta pulse is within a range of a rect pulse the product is a delta pulse weighted with the rect's height otherwise zero (sifting property). The following argumentation proofs that the delta pulse at mT_1 is for all m within the non zero domain of the rect at floor(m/beta)T_0. Therefor the expression can be simplified to the weighted delta pulse.

Comment: @travis are the clocks synchronous with themselves and the data?

Comment: @travis updated, hope it's reasonable

Comment: Just to clarify that this clock relationship is not valid if the clocks are not synchronous along with the data.

Comment: @user6972, the data are synchronous with respect to their own clock domain. They are asynchronous to each other when they cross the domain. I mean, x[n] is synchronous with Ctx and y[n] is synchronous with Crx. But y[n] is (usually) asynchronous with Ctx because the oversampling rate is (usually) not an integer.

Comment: @user6972... and this is covered by my solution and the reason for the floor function

Comment: @Alexander the floor only works if the data and clock are synchronous.  Often in "sampling" applications this isn't true, so it was just a word of caution. +1 for all the hard work.

Comment: @user6972 Thanks. When the data is delayed by a constant time in the Flip Flop, there would be an offset in the floor expression, I suppose. So in general the *floor idea* should work, but the question is about a zero delay model of the circuit.

Comment: @travis maybe you are interested in my slightly changed version. The representation (position) of the rect function was not correct. A rect which is high from 0 to T_0 is rect_{T_0}(t-T_0/2) and not rect_{T_0}(t-T_0). Just fixed it without any consequences for the result.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this:

$$y\left[m\right] = x\left[{\Big\lfloor{\frac{m}{\beta}}\Big\rfloor}\right]$$

Draw one or two exmples with different Betha to perform a sanity check.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are taking the absolute value? Counter-example: m=1 and beta=1.5. Then we get y[m] = x[2/3] which is invalid. In x[n], n must be an integer.

Comment: Correction,  y[1] = x[2/3].

Comment: Yes, absolute value. In your example (m=1, betha = 1.5):y[0] = x[0], y[1] = x[abs(1/1.5)]=x[0], y[2] = x[1], y[3] = x[2], etc..

Comment: Do you mean round instead of abs? Absolute value just changes a negative value into a positive one. It does not change a real number into an integer.

Comment: It is amazing how I can look at something wrong and claim it is right. Round, definitely round (down) :)

Comment: Changing to math notation: we have it! I think what you mean by "round down" is the floor function.

Comment: Offtopic. @Kaz, can you provide a link to any HOWTO on math notation?

Comment: @ Vasiliy Zukanov Try [this](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) out. It's a web editor that allows you to pick what you want to show with your mouse. It will generate code that can be interpreted by this site. In the answer use `/$` to open and close an inline block and `$$` to open and close block centered on the screen. Code being used it called \$TeX\$ and is very popular in mathematics circles. Also there are numerous tutorials on the Internet as well.

Comment: @VasiliyZukanov Nope. I remember much of it from having used TeX years ago, and Google for whatever I don't know.

Comment: Yes! y[m]=x[⌊m/β⌋] is exactly the expression I derived as well. And I think it is only valid if you make the assumption that the initial phase offset between the clocks is 0, but that is acceptable. Now... do you have any idea how we can prove this expression is correct? I wonder if there is some Z-transform property that can be used.

Comment: @travis this seems pretty obvious to me, but if you are out of phase it won't work by flooring it.  But if you're over sampling it should work out in the end.  What exactly is your concern?

Comment: I don't just want to know if it works or not, I want to know why it works.

Comment: @travis Will the clocks be synchronous with the data?